# Accessing a Record from API Source with Power Query (Custom Connector)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, vimeo-api

This is a follow up to my issue at [API Pagination in JSON Body (not Header) - How to Access with Power Query in Custom Connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72492453/api-pagination-in-json-body-not-header-how-to-access-with-power-query-in-cus)

I have built a custom connector for an API that sends its pagination data back in the body of the response, rather than the header. The way to use GetNextLink using header is documented in the GitHub custom connector example:

[https://github.com/microsoft/DataConnectors/blob/master/samples/Github/github.pq](https://I%20have%20built%20a%20custom%20connector%20for%20an%20API%20that%20sends%20its%20pagination%20data%20back%20in%20the%20body%20of%20the%20response,%20rather%20than%20the%20header.%20The%20way%20to%20use%20GetNextLink%20using%20header%20is%20documented%20in%20the%20GitHub%20custom%20connector%20example:%20%20%20%20%20https://github.com/microsoft/DataConnectors/blob/master/samples/Github/github.pq)

```
GetNextLink = (response, optional request) =>
    let
        // extract the "Link" header if it exists
        link = Value.Metadata(response)[Headers][#"Link"]?,
        links = Text.Split(link, ","),
        splitLinks = List.Transform(links, each Text.Split(Text.Trim(_), ";")),
        next = List.Select(splitLinks, each Text.Trim(_{1}) = "rel=""next"""),
        first = List.First(next),
        removedBrackets = Text.Range(first{0}, 1, Text.Length(first{0}) - 2)
    in
        try removedBrackets otherwise null;
```

Getting to the pagination data from the body of the response should be easier than the header, I've learned. But I am stumped.  In the images, you can see the record I am trying to access that comes back through Web.Contents()

[image]

This is my code for the GetNextLink function. I am trying to get the "next" record above.

```
GetNextLink = (response) =>
// response is data already run through Web.Contents()

let
   Source = Lines.FromBinary(response),
   nextPage = Record.Field(Source[paging], "next")
in 
   try nextPage otherwise null;
```

I get the error back "We cannot convert a value of type Record to type Text". I feel like I am not getting the 'Source" correctly? I could certainly use help as I am a PowerQuery newbie!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
GetNextLink = (response) =>
// response is data already run through Web.Contents()
let Source = Lines.FromBinary(response),
nextpage = try Source[paging][next] otherwise null
in nextpage
```

or

```
GetNextLink = (response) =>
// response is data already run through Web.Contents()
let  Source = Lines.FromBinary(response)
nextpage = try Record.Field(Source[paging],"next") otherwise null
in nextpage
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I think what you have for `nextpage` is spot on and you corrected my syntax. Unfortunately, I am still getting the "We cannot convert a value of type Record to type List" when trying to connect to the API. I feel like I've done enough testing that I've located this issue in the above GetNextLink function. I think it is to do with how we defining the Source, using the Lines.FromBinary method. The docs say this method "Converts a binary value to a list of text values split at lines breaks". Might be mixing lists/records. Is there another way to get the `response` in a variable? Thx!

Comment: If your data is a record inside a record, this would work.  I cant tell based on your data whats wrong.  Just try to use the interface.  Double click the record or right click and drill down and see what the resulting code is

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps there are issues elsewhere in the code. You've been very helpful